# Android 5.0 opening activity on top of another activity kills the first activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I am writing an app and have a bug I sincerely have no idea how to solve. I have two activities A and B, from activity A I press a button to start the B activity, but when I do that the layout activity A disappears. Note that B has a transparent background so user can see activity A elements. However I encounter this problem just on android 5.0 devices, on other Api levels the app works as intended to work. I hope someone had a similar problem or catches the problem in my logic. 
P.S. I declared activity's A launch mode as "singleTask", and B's as "standard". That's how I start the activity:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
```

Note that I do not call finnish() after start activity and I also tried to set all kinds of flags to the intent, but the problem persists and that just on android 5.0. 
here is the manifest code for the two activities:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MenuActivity"> </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GameActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in onCreate() in the GameActivity I start the MenuActivity like this:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

    initViews();

    Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using transparent Views or Fragments rather than Activities

Comment: That's how I've designed the first version and now it seemed more modulated and organized to use activities. Thank you a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: Go to developer options and see if `do not keep activities is checked`!

Comment: @Mandalin maybe you will want to look at the MVP design pattern to increase your modularity and organisation

Comment: @MuhammadBabar that was the first thing I checked

Comment: Add logging to the lifecycle methods (`onStop()`, `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` of `ActivityA` and see if any of these are getting called when you start `ActivityB`. Please show how you are setting the background in `ActivityB` to transparent. You could also try to make the height of the main layout of `ActivityB` a fixed size (ie: 500dp) instead of `match_parent` and see if you can then see part of `ActivityA` underneath. I'm guessing that `ActivityA` is still there, but the "transparency" of `ActivityB` is buggy. Just a hunch.

Comment: I see your point, but if Activity A was still there, why am I seeing elements of Activity B and in background I see the android laucher, if there was a problem with Activity B transparency wouldn't that block me to see the launcher? I will log the lifecycle methods to understand better what is happening with my activity. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Try this it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to this, I have already tried that flag with no results

Comment: Please share detailed code by which i can identify what the actual problem is ? May be you have done something wrong in manifest or in game activity while going to another activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I also tried this, no result. Remember that on other android versions the app works just fine.

Comment: @Madalin this problem is occurred in all 5.0 devices or any specific 5.0 device.

Comment: I had the problem both on emulator, and two different physical devices so I think it's a general problem